# How can I add array values to an object using destructuring?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I have variables here `firstName` which is `Faisal` and `lastName` which is `Iraqi`.

```
let str = "Faisal Iraqi";
let [firstName, lastName] = str.split(" ");
console.log(firstName, lastName);
console.log(str.split(" "));
```

so I should add this properties to my new object using destructuring:

```
let obj = {};
```

obj must return `firstName: "Faisal", lastName: "Iraqi"`

Comment: _"so I should add this properties to my new object using destructuring"_ - Why? Why not `let obj = { firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a destructuring assignment as you create new variables, you can directly destructure into the object properties:

```js
let str = "Faisal Iraqi";
let obj = {};

[obj.firstName, obj.lastName] = str.split(" ");

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add them to the object:

```
let obj = {firstName, lastName};
```

So the whole code looks like:

```
let str = "Faisal Iraqi";
let [firstName, lastName] = str.split(" ");
let obj = {firstName, lastName};
console.log(obj);
```